# How to fix: Error while executing ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git

Tags: ethereum

I am working with Material UI and React and while on my Windows and Ubuntu the app runs ok, on my colleagues Mac and Ubuntu the compiler gives this error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git
```

The only dependency I thought it was related to was ethereumjs which I removed because actually it wasn't needed, but the problem persists.
These are the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.4.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@material-ui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.0.0-beta.0",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.4.1",
    "@web3-react/core": "^6.1.9",
    "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
    "i18next": "^20.3.1",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.2.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.10.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-stepper-horizontal": "^1.0.11",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "web3": "^1.3.6"
},
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue - these dependencies install correctly on my machine. The `ethereumjs-abi` is probably a dependency of some of the listed dependencies. And you might have the SSH port blocked on your firewall / ISP / somewhere along the way.

Comment: I had the same error and I solved it by updating node and npm to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to `ethereumjs-abi` dependency which needs to be downloaded in `ssh` mode where the repo is cloned using https.

As a fix,  Adding github identity with `ssh-add` solves the issue.

`ssh-add -K <path to private key>`

```sh
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/github
Identity added: /Users/abc/.ssh/github
```