# How to fix-h -t ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git

Tags: reactjs, ssh, ethereum

Up to 2 days ago I could install all dependencies of my project without any problem, but since today I am getting this ssh error:

-h -t ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git

but the thing is that I do not have ethereumjs installed.
Here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "husky-farm",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.4.1",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.4.1",
        "@web3-react/core": "^6.1.9",
        "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
        "flag-icon-css": "^3.5.0",
        "i18next": "^20.3.1",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.1",
        "i18next-http-backend": "^1.2.6",
        "npm": "^7.19.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-i18next": "^11.10.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "react-stepper-horizontal": "^1.0.11",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
        "web3": "^1.3.6"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "bignumber.js": "^9.0.1",
        "dotenv-cli": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.30.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
        "ethers": "^5.4.1"
    }
}
```

Any idea why all of sudden it asks me an ssh key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first, as mentioned in the [comments of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68374802/6309), if  updating node and `npm` to the latest version.

As seen in [`smartcontractkit/truffle-starter-kit` issue 96](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/truffle-starter-kit/issues/96), consider also using [`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/), to test if this is more reliable than `npm` in your case.